# what does the void(*f) mean in -> "methodName( void (*f)(const Datatype&));"?

Tags: c++

So, I'm looking at one of the codes my professor gave me, but I don't know what the void(*f) means, could anyone clarify?

```
template<class T>
void BinaryTree<T>::inorder( void (*f)(const T&), BTNode<T> *node ) const //<-- right here
{
  if (!node)
    return;
  inorder(f, node->left); 
  f(node->elem);
  inorder(f, node->right);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a pointer to a function returning `void`, and taking  `const T&` parameter. The name of the pointer if `f`.

```
void foo(const T&);   // a function declaration

void (*f)(const T&);  // function pointer

f = &foo;             // Can assign &foo to f, return type and signature match
```

Answer (score 0):

In C++ a pointer `F` to a function that maps type `X` to type `Y` is denoted as `Y (*F)(X)`.

Answer (score 0):

this is afunction pointer.
the function gets a unction pointer as parameter.

but since this is already template c++ i would try to avoid this. It would be better to use functors instead. (but may be its a function pointer for a reason)